# Is it possible to limit what is logged in ODBC logging in IIS 6.0?

Tags: windows-server-2003, logging, iis-6

I am using ODBC logging in IIS *6.0*.  I cannot change that.  Is there a way to limit it's logging to just the actual pages requested as opposed to every single tiny thing requested on a page?  I don't need to know if some gif on page x was requested.  I only want to know page x was requested.

Is this possible?